# implementing runat in HtmlTextWriterAttribute

Tags: c#, runat

## Hi dear friends, i have web custom control

this render function of Window class

```
    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter wr)
    {
        wr.AddAttribute("runat", "server",true);
        wr.AddAttribute("id", this.UniqueID, false);
        wr.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);
        wr.RenderEndTag();
        wr.WriteLine();
        base.RenderContents(wr);
    }
```

---

## Use on web page:

`(cc1:Window ID="Window1" runat="server" )
(div) runat="server" id="aaaa"(/div)`

---

## Browser sourse result:

`(span id="Window1")(div runat="server" id="Window1")
(/div)
span)
(div) id="aaaa"(/div)`

Comment: Did you actually have a question?

Answer (score 1):

You never once in your question actually state a question. Anyhow, I think you want your custom control to render like a `<div runat="server">`.

```
public class Window : WebControl {
    public Window() : base(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div) {}

    protected override void AddAttributesToRender(HtmlTextWriter writer) {
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id, UniqueID);
    }
}
```

1. You should call the constructor on WebControl which accepts a HtmlTextWriterTag.
2. You should override AddAttributesToRender (instead of RenderContents) to add attributes to your element.
3. `runat="server"` is only used during parsing of your html code, and have no use in your controls.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>I am not sure if your example of use is just typo and formatting errors when posting, or if it is actually this way you use it (exept I understand that you posted `<...>` as `(...)`, which is not my issue here).</sub>

---

You should start with implementing your control class as [suggested by Simon Svensson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591848/implementing-runat-in-htmltextwriterattribute/4591935#4591935).

Then, if you want your div with id="aaaa" be a html tag inside your controls div tag, you should use it like this (note the ending `</cc1:Window>`):

### Use on web page:

```
<cc1:Window ID="Window1" runat="server">
  <div id="aaaa">Text content here</div>
</cc1:Window>
```

### Browser source result:

```
<div id="Window1">
  <div id="aaaa">Text content here</div>
</div>
```

As Simon said, `runat="server"` is mainly used for server controls, and has no meaning for the rendered HTML controls.